# Как удалить все div'ы с одинаковым значением span?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть множество

```
<div class="block">
<span>значение</span>
</div>
```

Как можно с помощью js или jquery удалить все div'ы с этим классом,если значения  совпадают,т.е оставить только самый первый.

Comment: Что Вы уже пробовали, и  что у Вас не получилось?

Comment: Я даже не представляю как это примерно реализовать.

Comment: Но нашел что-то похожее var list = Object.create(null);
    $( 'li[data-name]' ).each(function(){
      var $li = $(this),
       name = $li.data('name');
     if(name in list) $li.css('display', 'none');
     else list[name] = true;
       });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = {};

$('.block').each(function() {
  if (obj[$(this).children().text()]) {
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    obj[$(this).children().text()] = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение1</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение1</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое)

Comment: Рад помочь) Обращайтесь))

Answer (score 2):

Ответ-дополнение, о том как решить данную задачу на чистом JavaScript.

---

Эквивалент кода в принятом ответе:

```
let obj = {}; 

for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.block')) {
  if (typeof obj[el.textContent] !== 'undefined')
    el.remove();
  else
    obj[el.textContent] = true;
}
```

*Сравнение типа с `undefined` необходимо и в решении на jQuery - иначе, элементы с пустыми значениями (`<span></span>`) будут пропускаться.*

---

**Более гибкое решение** (и без лишнего буферного объекта):

```js
// ref - селектор "образца", elements (опционально) - селектор элементов для поиска
function removeDuplicates(ref, elements = ref) {
  let count = 0; 
  if (ref = document.querySelector(ref)) {
    const txt = ref.textContent.trim().toLowerCase(); 
    for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(elements)) {
      if (el !== ref && el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === txt)
        el.remove(), count++; 
    }
  }
  return count; 
}

const n = removeDuplicates('#reference .block', '.block'); 
console.log('Удалено элементов: ' + n);
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span>значение</span>
</div>
<section id="reference">
  <div class="block">
    <span>значение</span>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>не значение</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>Значение</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Если несколько разных повторяющихся блоков, то этот код работать не будет. но для одного повторяющегося блока очень даже подходит. ))

Comment: @IliaBrykin, прекрасно будет работать... `['.block1', '.block2'].forEach(s => removeDuplicates(s);` или `for (s of ['.block1', '.block2']) removeDuplicates(s);`.

Comment: А если класс один, а значения разные?

Comment: @IliaBrykin, тогда ВНЕЗАПНО это разные блоки, а не дубликаты :)) ТС ведь пишет "если значения совпадают", под значениями подразумевая текстовый контент...

Comment: я имел ввиду такую ситуацию: <div class="block">
  <span>значение</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение1</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>значение1</span>
</div>а В общем для конкртено этого задания все верно)) Приятно с умным человеком поговорить))

Comment: @IliaBrykin, в таком случае да, не сработает с `.block` - потому что это селектор не того образца. В таком случае правильнее будет передать первым аргументом что-то типа `.block:nth-of-type(3)`. Ну, или можно вернуться к варианту с буферным объектом, объединив оба подхода (только я бы сокращал выборку элементов на каждой итерации, например через типкаст в массив и шифт - чтобы исключить повторную проверку одних и тех же).

Comment: Ну, метод `includes()` и жквери ведь используют тот же итератор что и `for`, поэтому удаление уже проверенных из выборки-массива значительно ускорит выполнение _любой_ реализации, когда элементов овердофига :) Тем более что коллекция в массив типкастится буквально одним вызовом, или спред-оператором.